# QSqlTableModel отображение файлов BLOB

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2, qtableview

Есть таблица в которой хранятся по мимо обычной информации также PDF документы в виде **`BLOB`**, которые отображаются вот так в виде знаков вопросов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать эти "знаки вопросов" более дружелюбнее пользователю? (Иконку бы какую-нибудь туда засунуть или что-то еще, а то я сразу предвкушаю вопрос, от пользователя: "А что это за знаки вопросов?")

Минимальный пример (рядом с файлом кода нужно положить любой файл с названием **test_BLOB.jpg**, что бы было что конвертировать в **`BLOB`**):

```
import sys
import os
from PySide2 import QtSql
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from PySide2 import QtCore


class Storage_app(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.createConnection()
        self.fillTable()  # !!! тестовое заполнение базы данных
        self.createModel()
        self.initUI()

        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.view)

        if not parent:
            self.show()

    def createConnection(self):
        self.db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
        self.db.setDatabaseName("local_base.db")  # !!! .db
        if not self.db.open():
            print("Cannot establish a database connection")
            return False

    def fillTable(self):
        """
        Вспомогательная функция заполнениия базы данных
        Отключить после тестового запуска
        """
        file_path = (f"{os.getcwd()}\\test_BLOB.jpg")
        test_BLOB = self.convertToBinaryData(file_path)
        test_BLOB = QtCore.QByteArray(test_BLOB)

        self.db.transaction()
        q = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
        #
        q.exec_("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS company;")
        q.exec_("CREATE TABLE company ("
                "id INT PRIMARY KEY, "
                "name_company TEXT NOT NULL, "
                "blob_data BLOB NOT NULL );")

        # Вставка тестовых значений
        query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
        query.prepare("INSERT INTO company (id, name_company, blob_data) "
                      "VALUES (:id, :name_company, :blob_data)")

        query.bindValue(":id", 1)
        query.bindValue(":name_company", 'АО КОПЫТА')
        query.bindValue(":blob_data", test_BLOB)
        query.exec_()

        query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
        query.prepare("INSERT INTO company (id, name_company, blob_data) "
                      "VALUES (:id, :name_company, :blob_data)")

        query.bindValue(":id", 2)
        query.bindValue(":name_company", 'АО РОГА')
        query.bindValue(":blob_data", test_BLOB)
        query.exec_()

        self.db.commit()

    def createModel(self):
        """
        Создание модели для отображения
        """
        self.model = QtSql.QSqlRelationalTableModel()
        self.model.setTable("company")
        self.model.setHeaderData(0, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "id")
        self.model.setHeaderData(1, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Наиманование")
        self.model.setHeaderData(2, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Документы")
        self.model.select()

    def initUI(self):
        self.view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        mode = QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection
        self.view.setSelectionMode(mode)


    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if (self.db.open()):
            self.db.close()

    def convertToBinaryData(self, file_path):
        # Конвертирование в BLOB
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
            blobData = file.read()
        return blobData


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    w = Storage_app()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: @ S. Nick, спасибо за внимание, добавил)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как говорится sorry for my terrible python (знаю его поверхностно), но надеюсь поймете..

Вам необходимо сделать кастомную модель данных, и переопределить для нужного столбца DisplayRole чтобы скрыть текст (ромбики-вопросики) и DecorationRole для вывода иконки

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtSql import *

db_file = "test.db3"

def create_connection(file_path):
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    db.setDatabaseName(file_path)
    if not db.open():
        print("Cannot establish a database connection to {}!".format(file_path))
        return False
    return True


def fill_tables():
    q = QSqlQuery()
    q.exec_("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Manufacturers;")
    q.exec_("CREATE TABLE Manufacturers (Company TEXT, Country TEXT,Blob_data BLOB NOT NULL);")
    q.exec_("INSERT INTO Manufacturers VALUES ('VW', 'Germany','an blob data');")
    q.exec_("INSERT INTO Manufacturers VALUES ('Honda' , 'Japan', 'another blob data');")

# Тут описываем нашу кастомную модель, основанную на qsqltablemodel
class myTableModel(QSqlTableModel):
    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole): # Переопределяем метод data
        if index.column() == 2 and role == Qt.DisplayRole: # для второго столбца, скроем выводимый текст
            return ""; 
        if index.column() == 2 and role == Qt.DecorationRole: # и для него же выведем иконку в качестве декора
            return QIcon.fromTheme("folder")
        return QSqlTableModel.data(self,index, role) # все остальное должно штатно обработаться qsqltablemodel


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    if not create_connection(db_file):
        sys.exit(-1)

    fill_tables()

    view = QTableView()
# Модель создаем уже свою кастомную
    model = myTableModel()
    model.setTable("Manufacturers")
    model.select()
    view.setModel(model)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Результат получается следующий. При этом не важно BLOB у вас или что-то другое. Переопределяя модель вы можете сделать что угодно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Tatarincev, огромнейше вас благодарю! Как раз то что нужно)